# Visualizing the CLARA cluster center/medoid

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis, cluster-computing, k-means

I visualized my CLARA results using fviz_cluster (ggplot2) and I would like to have the medoids of each cluster more prominent (like changing their shape or color, etc) than other data points. The issue is, I have more than 800,000 data points and it is impossible to see it just through the "show.clust.cent".

How can I color the medoids with different colors and make them so much bigger than other data points, or make other data points invisible except the medoids? I also tried to use the star.plot but somehow it didn't work.

I know the line number of the medoids and thought to add it manually, but I also don't know how to integrate it to the fviz_cluster.

Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

```
fviz_cluster(clara.res,
         palette = c("#004c6d",
                     "#00ffff",
                     "#00a1c1",
                     "#6efa75",
                     "#78ab63",
                     "#cc0089",
                     "#ffc334",
                     "#ff9509",
                     "#ffb6de",
                     "#00cfe3"
                      ), # color palette
         ellipse.type = "t",geom = "point",show.clust.cent = TRUE,repel = TRUE,pointsize = 0.5,
         ggtheme = theme_classic()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Will this be ok for you?

```
library(tidyverse)

fpoint = function(n) tibble(
  Dlm1 = rnorm(n, sample(-20:20,1), sample(1:5,1)),
  Dlm2 = rnorm(n, sample(-20:20,1), sample(1:5,1))
)

df = tibble(cluster = paste(1:10)) %>% 
  mutate(data = map(cluster, ~fpoint(1000))) %>% 
  unnest(data)

df %>% ggplot(aes(Dlm1, Dlm2, color=cluster))+
  geom_point(alpha = 0.2, pch=21)+
  stat_ellipse(size=0.7)
```

[image]

Write data to `tibble` and use standard `ggplot`.

**Update 1**

```
library(factoextra)
library(cluster)
df = USArrests %>%  na.omit() %>% scale()
kmed = pam(df, k = 4)
fviz_cluster(kmed, data = df, alpha=0.3, geom = "point", show.clust.cent = TRUE,repel = TRUE, pointsize = 2)
```

[image]

Is that the point?

Comment: Hi Marek, no, unfortunately, I still won't be able to see the medoids with this :(

Comment: Have you seen my update? By appropriately setting the `alpha` parameter (for points) you will be able to see the medioids without any problems. Does this solve your problem?